# Where can I find a list of common US income tax deductions?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

Where can I find a list of common tax deductions in the US?  I'd like to know so I can keep more receipts and pay less tax.

Comment: Could you please specify: For strictly personal income taxes, or for a small business, perhaps?

Comment: @Chris I was asking in regards to personal income taxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A decent list can be found here: http://www.fivecentnickel.com/2008/01/29/common-tax-deductions/.

Keep in mind that you will need to read the IRS codes regarding these for details, but those are the common deductions when you itemize your Federal personal income tax in the United States of America.

Comment: Thanks @Mike!  I think the medical deduction rules are about to change (going to 10% from 7.5%).